# PHP - Use "[ ]" to pass parameters as array

Tags: php, arrays, parameters

I have a function that receives parameters as an array:

```
public myFunction($options = array("option1"=>true, "option2"=>true, "option4"=>"astring"), $anotherparameter = 0) {
    if($options["option1"] === true) {
         //And here all the magic is done
    }
}
```

When I use it somewhere else I use something like this:

```
myFunction(["option1"=>false], 1) { //Magic }
```

I have installed PHP 5.5 on my localhost and this WORKS, when I upload it to my remote server it throws an error, and I have to put the array parameters like:

```
myFunction(array("option1"=>false), 1) { //Magic }
```

Is it due to PHP version? The remote server has PHP 5.3, I just updated it to 5.4, but I want to know if I need an specific version of PHP to work with this kind of array syntax, or should I use always array(...) format?

Answer (score 3):

The array short syntax `[]` was added in PHP 5.4 :)

See:  http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: Thank you! I will then update my servers to PHP 5.4 now that I know I can use it safely with this version! I just didn't know how to research for that specific subject, so I asked here